# Python: How to integrate a column using Monte Carlo?

Tags: python

I want to calculate this integral (you can see in the image) using Monte Carlo but the function Yk(X) is a column in the table named data1:

[image]

I've tried this code but I'm not sure:

```
def MonteCarlo(a,b):
    Y_kk = random.choices(data1['Y_k'], k = len(data1)) ##new vector that take random values of the Y_k column in data1
    I=0;
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        I = I + Y_kk[i]
    I = I*(b-a)/len(data1)
    return I;
```

Comment: There is absolutely no point in doing Monte Carlo if you are choosing the same number of point as in your dataset.  Just use the data points one by one.  Do your data points actually represent a set of results from -1 to 1?

Comment: If you actually use all values of the "Y_k" column, there is no need to choose randomly from them.

Comment: You could just do `I = sum(data1['Y-k']) * (b-a) / len(data1)`.  Same thing.